# How to nest '#If' conditions?

Tags: autohotkey

I have tried the following, it throws an error, "unexpected {":

```
#If !(MG_Active){
    #If WinActive("ahk_exe foobar2000.exe")
        WheelUp::
            ToolTip, foobar2000 Up
            Return
        WheelDown::
            ToolTip, foobar2000 Down
            return
    
    #If WinActive("ahk_exe firefox.exe")
        WheelUp::
            ToolTip, firefox Up
            Return
        WheelDown::
            ToolTip, firefox Down
            return
}
```

The following does not seem to work at all:

```
#If
    #If WinActive("ahk_exe foobar2000.exe")
        WheelUp::
            ToolTip, foobar2000 Up
            Return
        WheelDown::
            ToolTip, foobar2000 Down
            return
    
    #If WinActive("ahk_exe firefox.exe")
        WheelUp::
            ToolTip, firefox Up
            Return
        WheelDown::
            ToolTip, firefox Down
            return
#If,
```

This works but I would like to reserve the use `&&` for something else:

```
#If WinActive("ahk_exe foobar2000.exe") && !(MG_Active)
    WheelUp::
        ToolTip, foobar2000 Up
        Return
    WheelDown::
        ToolTip, foobar2000 Down
        return

#If WinActive("ahk_exe firefox.exe") && !(MG_Active)
    WheelUp::
        ToolTip, firefox Up
        Return
    WheelDown::
        ToolTip, firefox Down
        return
```

Is it possible to get something akin to the first or second example?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Forgot using #EndIf to enclose properly at any place? And please specify the syntax or programming language, using just a single tag isn't enough.

Comment: @HarshitGupta, its AutoHotkey, I tagged it as so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine as many conditions as you want within an If-statement or #If directive - provided the combination is logical.

```
#If !(MG_Active) && ( WinActive("ahk_exe firefox.exe") || WinActive("ahk_class Notepad") )

    $a:: MsgBox, b

#If ( (MG_Active) && WinActive("ahk_exe firefox.exe") ) && !WinExist("ahk_class Notepad")

    $a:: MsgBox, c

#If 

$a:: MsgBox, d
```